# How can I get rid of varicose veins from my face?

Tags: personal-care

Varicose veins are enlarged, weakened and visible veins under the skin surface, usually in a dark purple or blue color. In sunlight, these are very prominent on my face, which is very embarrassing for me. What can I do to get rid of them?

Comment: I don't want to be a buzzkill, but this is a **medical** condition and there are **medical** treatments for this - please do not take anyone's advice here, especially if they sound good - go see a doctor and ask exactly what you ask here.

Comment: Ok i agree with you but i thought that may be there will be any home remedy for removing it like something can be eate ,because it's a sign of weakness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't need a lifehack as described [here](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto), it needs medical advice.

Answer (score 2):

**Seek competent  medical professional advice not this website.** Varicose veins may indicate a underlying condition pertaining to blood circulation in the body. Depending how serious they are there could be issues with clots. For more info check this link from the mayo clinic. This link talks about the symptoms,causes and risk factors for varicose veins.

https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/varicose-veins/symptoms-causes/syc-20350643

**This is a medical condition not a life hack.**